# Проблема с Gradle NDK Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle

Добрый день, столкнулся с такой проблемой. 
В нашем проекте мы используем gradle и buildFlavor

```
 productFlavors {
        arm {
            versionCode Integer.parseInt("8" + defaultConfig.versionCode)
            ndk {
                abiFilter "armeabi"
            }
        }
        x86 {
            versionCode Integer.parseInt("6" + defaultConfig.versionCode)
            ndk {
                abiFilter "x86"
            }
        }
        mips {
            versionCode Integer.parseInt("4" + defaultConfig.versionCode)
            ndk {
                abiFilter "mips"
            }
        }
        armv7 {
            versionCode Integer.parseInt("2" + defaultConfig.versionCode)
            ndk {
                abiFilter "armeabi"
            }
        }
    }
```

Сейчас возникла потребность использования библиотеки, которая предоставляет только arm/arm7/mips библиотеки, есть ли возможность игнорирования этой библиотеки на x86/x64 ?

Comment: Лучше проверить. Скорее всего, будет работать, за счет того, что на x86 устройствах arm бинарники благодаря libhoudini - транслятору кода arm в x86, но раза в 2 медленнее. Но могут возникнуть проблемы из-за того, что уже есть какие-то x86 бинарники. Т.е. если там будут только arm бинарники, то работать будет точно